# fread in data.table but too many columns

Tags: r, data.table

I've recently updated my data.table package, and I'm struggling with the `fread()` function.  Previously, (version 1.10.4-3) if I used `fread()` it could delimit the data I was reading in into columns. The newer version can't do this, and if I use the `fill = TRUE` tag it chucks it all into onto column.

The issue is that it detects there are 13 column names, but the new version of data.table tries to fill the other columns.  Is there a way to still do this?

This is my input, but new data.table can no longer delimit the columns correctly.

I'm aware there might be other packages that might do this, but I'd prefer to use data.table if possible.

```
    id, value, other
    1, "("a"="b", "b"="c", "c"="d")", 2
    2, "("a"="b", "b"="c", "c"="d")", 3
```

Comment: Can you share a few rows of the file you are attempting to read, not just the incorrect result? As well as your `fread` call?

Comment: @GregorThomas - done, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: I think this example can be made a lot simpler to make it easier to debug. See my suggested edit and check if it is representative. Trying to identify the issue with 3 chunks might be easier than hundreds.

Comment: I might be totally stupid and not reading the `?fread` help file correctly, but it should just work for the example given as the quotes are matched. I can't even get the 'embedded quote' example in the `?fread` help to parse correctly. I am stumped.

Comment: @thelatemail me too.  I've tried everything I can think of, and I'm absolutely stumped.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There have been changes to the quote rules from version 1.10.6. They're now more robust and have better performance, but will not handle unbalanced quotes and other cases. Check the details for quotes on the current documentation of fread.

As alternative, you can use functions that use `scan` to handle quotes inside quotes, like `read.table`:

```
read.table("example.txt", sep = ",", header = TRUE)
```

Or, as [answered by @jared-mamrot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65228198/9817508), use `vroom` for better performance, converting later to a data.table with `setDT`

Answer (score 5):

[Vroom](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2019/05/vroom-1-0-0/) handles your test-case without adding additional columns, e.g.

```
library(vroom)
test <- vroom(file = "test.txt")
test
# A tibble: 2 x 3
     id value           other
  <dbl> <chr>           <dbl>
1     1 (a=b, b=c, c=d)     2
2     2 (a=b, b=c, c=d)     3
```

**EDIT**

To keep the quotation marks:

```
library(vroom)
test <- vroom(file = "test.txt", escape_double = FALSE)
test
# A tibble: 2 x 3
     id value                                     other
  <dbl> <chr>                                     <dbl>
1     1 ("a"="b", "b"="c", "c"="d")     2
2     2 ("a"="b", "b"="c", "c"="d")     3
```

Comment: `read.csv` gives similar results, noting that this actually changes `"a"="b"` etc to `a=b`

Comment: @jarod_mamrot -thanks, but this removes the quote marks, and I need to keep them